# Inaccessible voice memo

Tags: iphone

[image]

This 3-hour long voice memo that I recorded yesterday comes up when I search my phone but doesn’t show up in voice memos. I initially thought my phone is taking time to process this and it would show up later, but it hasn’t. Can I access this in any way?

Comment: What happens if you tap on it from the search screen?

Comment: @nohillside Takes me to voice memos, the recording doesn’t show up there though. If I search for a voice memo that does show up and tap on it from the search screen, it takes me to voice memos, to the selected recording, but not for this one.

Answer (score 1):

The paid app [iExplorer](https://macroplant.com/iexplorer) can show Voice Memos in a Finder-like interface. iExplorer has a free trial which will allow you to verify if the Voice Memo exists as a file on your iPhone. You will need to [purchase the app](https://macroplant.com/iexplorer/free-vs-paid) to download the memo file.

[image]

*Disclaimer*: I'm a highly satisfied user of iExplorer and I'm not connected with Macroplant LLC financially or otherwise.